# win 64 bit application using lotus C API (v8.5)

Tags: c, windows, 64-bit, lotus-notes

I need to export Lotus NSF database documents to XML. I am using Lotus C API (8.5). I have already build a 32 bit windows application and now I need to port it to 64 bit application. I am not sure if 64 application is supported. If possible, I would like to know how to build it in visual studio.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might have some useful information as well:  http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/C-Callouts_on_non-32-bit_Platforms